# Dump BIOS from Mobo with no visual output?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure, dump

I have a hardware problem  or with an ASUS P5N-D motherboard.

Issues:

1. No visibility of whether the Mobo POSTs since no output from 2 Graphics cards using the PCI-E slot - no other display output method I can think of.
2. Devices (that work fine) when connected USB ports on Mobo, and USB sockets on Mobo do not function (eg no lights on keyboard).
3. I cannot access BIOS to check settings since no output on monitor when connected to the graphics cards (monitor has no issue since can display when connected to another computer).

I suspect one or more settings has been changed in the BIOS on the P5N-D. Possibility of other motherboard components such as Graphics controllers on Mobo not working correctly.

What works on the Mobo:

- Power light comes on.
- Intel CPU fan spins.

Further info:

1. Do not know if there are any beeps from mobo since currently no internal speaker. Have ordered some.
2. Tried many RAM sticks in each different DIMM.
3. Tried removing CMOS battery, and cleared CMOS.

What I want to know:

1. Methods for viewing and dumping BIOS data for this situation?
2. How to use any hardware mentioned or other devices to get information on the Mobo and BIOS?
3. A BIOS dump from a working P5N-D motherboard, so I can see what it should be, and help find what the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to reset your CMOS to default, this should give you a working output but from what you describe you have a totalled MOBO

Comment: OP has already dome this as stated in his question "Tried removing CMOS battery, and cleared CMOS"

Comment: I'm aware of that, thats why I said "from what you describe you have a totalled MOBO"

Comment: @todda You have an _answer_  to your deleted question [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11132/to-stink-or-not-to-stink). :-)